# How to redirect Crash report's email address to my email (for my cocoa app)

Tags: cocoa, macos, crash, report

I'd like to know if there is any way how to set default OS X Crash reporter email address to my email address (for my cocoa application).

I'd like to get my Crash reports to my email, not Apple's. ;)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As *mipadi* stated, crash reports arent sent by email, but are uploaded to some Apple server. To intercept this and/or send it to your own server there are already several classes and frameworks to handle this, here are a few:

More sophisticated (catch the event):

- [Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) (by Google, catches the event, generates its own crash dump (`minidump`) and *simulates* the Apple crash reporter interface with your company name in it)
- [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) (Similar to Breakpad, catches the event, generates its own crash dump, but no default UI is provided. The library is best suited for iOS -- it was written to operate within the AppStore's constraints, and x86-64 support on Mac OS X remains experimental).

Simple (read the crash dumps):

- [UKCrashReporter](http://zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm)
- [SFBCrashReporter](https://launchpad.net/sfbcrashreporter)
- [ILCrashReporter](http://www.infinite-loop.dk/developer/)

Answer (score 1):

No, crash reports always go to Apple. If you want to automatically receive copies of your application's crash reports, you'll have to write your own solution. One way would be to check `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` for `.crash` files containing your app's name, and automatically email them to you, although that'll add overhead to your program so you'll have to decide if it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this article: http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/860/crash-reporter-roundup