# Mac OS Crash Report Tool

Tags: macos

When something goes wrong in my Mac OS application, like a NULL pointer exception or something like that, OS X pops up a "problem report" window inviting the user to send a report of the problem to Apple. Is there any way to have the same information displayed in a window that prompts them to report it directly to us, instead?

Also, how do you get access to the reports people send? I assume it involves signing up for the mac OS developer program?

Comment: You can find some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805171/how-to-redirect-crash-reports-email-address-to-my-email-for-my-cocoa-app/